# multinominal logit model - using the likelihood ratio test to test for joint significance

Tags: self-study

I have estimated a multinominal logit model & now I have been asked to test for joint significance of two variables using the Likelihood ratio test. I just wanted to ask why & how would you do this? I thought that the Wald test would have been more appropriate? In previous subjects I used the LR test by estimating a restricted model & unrestricted model & then calculating the ratio - is it the same method for joint significance?

Comment: You are right that the Wald test is preferable, particularly when you are using complex survey structures and weights that lead to you estimating a pseudo likelihood instead of a likelihood. In other occasions the likelihood ratio test for joint significance works well and is performed as you describe: fit constrained and unconstrained models and take the ratio. Do you need insight on which commands to use? If so, perhaps it is better that you tell us which software you use.

Comment: Thanks Kenji, I am using eviews. Could you please provide some help as to what commands I need to use?

Comment: Hi. I don't use eviews, so I can't help you much here. You can try and see if Stack Overflow has a tag on that. I'll create a proper answer below based on my comment and add some Stata lines, in case they are helpful to you or to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that the Wald test is preferable, particularly when you are using complex survey structures and weights that lead to you estimating a pseudo likelihood instead of a likelihood.

In other occasions the likelihood ratio test for joint significance works well and is performed as you describe: fit constrained and unconstrained models and take the ratio.

In Stata 14, here is an example from the manuals:

```
//Load Hosmer & Lemeshow data from web
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/lbw

//Estimate the model without constraints
logit low age lwt i.race smoke ptl ht ui

//Store the model as 'full_model'
estimates store full_model

//estimate the model with constraints
logit low i.race smoke ui


//Test the current model '.' against the model without constraints
lrtest full_model .
```

This should give you a test of joint significance for the variables `age`, `lwt`, `ptl`, and `ht`.